# Find text only of style "Heading 1" (Range.Find to match style)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find some text in my document that only appears in "Heading 1" styles. So far, no avail.

**Sample Code:**

```
With ThisDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = "The Heading"
    .Style = "Heading 1" 'Does not work
    .Execute
    If .Found Then Debug.Print "Found"
End With
```

Just a note, it keeps stopping at the table of contents.

Edit: fixed the mispelt 'if' statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. My best guess is that the 'Heading 1' style exists in your table of contents?

The code below should continue the find, finding all occurrences:

```
Dim blnFound As Boolean

With ThisDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = "The Heading"
    .Style = "Heading 1"

    Do
        blnFound = .Execute
        If blnFound Then
            Debug.Print "Found"
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mate. Is there a way to print out information about each found item (such as page number or trailing text)? I need to insert some text before it and can't seem to figure out the best way/if its possible.

Comment: Replacing Debug.Print "Found" with Debug.Print .Parent.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) wil return the line number

Comment: What happens if I expect the script to run on different language versions of Word? In Hungarian it's `"Címsor 1"` instead of `"Heading 1"` and so on. Is there no built in reference to that without a string key?

Comment: @marczellm I don't believe you can reference the default styles as static variables, at least as far as I have researched. This is probably because you can create your own or modify the existing styles. I guess you just have to cater for different languages as above, or using wildcards perhaps?

Comment: @MattRowles Since then I've seemingly found the solution to the builtin style referencing problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbuiltinstyle(v=office.11).aspx, but I didn't try it.

Comment: @marczellm I've just tested it and it works. Replace .Style = 'Heading 1' with .Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1 and it works. Good find mate!

Answer (score 2):

The reason I think it is not working is because you have to set the

```
.format = true
```

flag, and you *may* have to specify the style via the .Styles method:

```
With ThisDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = "The Heading"
    .Format = true   <<< -------- Tells Word to look for a special formatting
    .Style = ThisDocument.Styles("Heading 1")

    Do
        blnFound = .Execute
        If blnFound Then
           Debug.Print "Found"
        Else
           Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question on Google and the code in the question did not work for me. I have made the following changes to fix it:

- I changed `Selection.Find.Style = "Heading 1"` to an object.
- I changed the code to grab the boolean result of the search from `.Execute` rather than `.Found`

I hope this helps some other Googlers.

```
With ThisDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = "The Heading"
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")

    Dim SearchSuccessful As Boolean
    SearchSuccessful = .Execute

    If SearchSuccessful Then
        ' code
    Else
        ' code
    End If
End With
```