# Find all text formatted with given color

Tags: vba, ms-word, format, find-replace

I am looking for a way to create a new document containing all the text with a specific format from my document.

See below for what I wrote so far, but I'm stuck here:

- how do I stop my loop when end of document is reached? or how do I add intelligence to my code to avoid a static loop, and rather do a "scan all my document"?

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
   Dim objWord  As Application
   Dim objDoc As Document
   Dim objSelection As Selection

    Dim mArray() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    For i = 1 To 100
      ReDim Preserve mArray(i)
      With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .Execute
      End With

      mArray(i) = Selection.Text

    Next

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
   objWord.Visible = True
   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

    For i = 1 To 100
    objSelection.TypeText (mArray(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can loop through all words in the document with `For i = 1 To ThisDocument.Words.Count - 1` then you can access the word with `ThisDocument.Words(i)`

Comment: Currently, I want to make as many search as there is occurrences to find... but if I can count how many occurrences there are, then I'm good with your method, thanks.

Comment: There are tons of examples on using Find in Word, hard to believe you haven't found them... The `Find.Execute` returns a boolean value - True if the find was successful. Declare a Boolean variable, set it to True or False and use it in a Do-loop around the Find, testing whether Find.Execute was successful. If it was, continue; if not, the loop has finished. The `wdFindStop` you already have in your code will prevent Word from starting again at the top of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Cindy's nice tip (I could also have found relevant information in [Loop through Word document, starting from beginning of file at start of each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616541/loop-through-word-document-starting-from-beginning-of-file-at-start-of-each-loo)), and in case this could help someone some day:

1. define the format you are looking for thanks to Word's Macro Recorder
2. position yourself at the beginning of your document
3. Use a `while` loop checking `wdFindStop` -- It also demonstrate how to use Array of String in VBA--:

...

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim mArray() As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    isFound = True
    i = 1
    'For i = 1 To 40
    Do While (isFound)
      ReDim Preserve mArray(i)
      With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        isFound = .Execute
      End With
      mArray(i) = Selection.Text
      i = i + 1
    Loop
    'Next
    n = i - 2
    MsgBox n & " occurrences found."

    '
    ' create a new document with the phrases found

    Dim objWord  As Application
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim objSelection As Selection
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    For i = 1 To n 'mArray's Size
      objSelection.TypeText (mArray(i))
      objSelection.TypeParagraph
    Next
End Sub
```

NB: I could also have greatly benefited from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953%28v=office.11%29.aspx that explains how to find without changing the selection:

```
 With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
  .Text = "blue"
  .Forward = True
  .Execute
  If .Found = True Then .Parent.Bold = True
 End With
```

And from here: [Find text only of style "Heading 1" (Range.Find to match style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286927/find-text-only-of-style-heading-1-range-find-to-match-style)