# How to detect column number of selected text in a MSWord array?

Tags: vba, format, ms-word

I have to sum up a report based on the color of the text. If I find blue text, I write it to another document. I would like to highlight some of this text found based on its position in the Word array I found it.

On my page I have a simple table like below, with 2 or 3 columns. I'm already able to find and copy all the blue text in another document (see [Find all text formatted with given color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540753/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-the-text-formatted-with-given-color-in-ms-word)). 
[image]

I use below `vba` to find the next item:

```
  With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlue
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .Execute
  End With
```

and result of the search is available in `Selection.Text`.

Now what I need to know is once the text is selected, **is it possible to know the column number it is in?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Selection.Find` is successful it should leave the found text selected. Then this should give you the index of the column:

```
Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeColumnNumber)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!